# Bootstrap: Override background-color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is my files structure:

```
│   styles.scss
│   _bootstrap-overrides.scss
│   _global.scss
│   _mixins.scss
│   _nav.scss
│   _resume-item.scss
│   _variables.scss
```

Main file is `styles.scss`:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.scss";
@import "mixins.scss";
// Global CSS
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import "global.scss";
@import "nav.scss";
@import "resume-item.scss";
@import "bootstrap-overrides.scss";
```

As you can see, I import my `*.scss` files and bootstrap.

Everything works fine, I mean, background-color is orange:

[image]

However, I've moved these files into an `scss` folder now:

```
│   styles.scss
├───scss
│       _bootstrap-overrides.scss
│       _global.scss
│       _mixins.scss
│       _nav.scss
│       _resume-item.scss
│       _variables.scss
```

Into `_variables.scss`:

```
$primary:       $orange !default;
```

However, background color is blue:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you changed the "styles.scss" after you moved these files into an scss folder?

May be it will be looks like this:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "scss/variables.scss";
@import "scss/mixins.scss";
// Global CSS
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import "scss/global.scss";
@import "scss/nav.scss";
@import "scss/resume-item.scss";
@import "scss/bootstrap-overrides.scss";
```

Comment: I has worked. Why `variables` and `mixins` have to be imported before `bootstrap`?

Answer (score 1):

I've a notion that

```
$body-bg:
```

Is the variable you need to mess with. Check your variables scss file for it.

Comment: Sorry, The problem is not related with which variable I need to override, but it's related with files structure. I've edited post, I've been able to show background color orange but after having changed the files structure, background-color is turned to blue...